# How To Popup whole Div without changing its content position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, zooming, integer-division

I want to popup the whole div that contain image,div,etc . but problem is that  when i popup div the position of within div is changed. i  want to zoom the div that display like popup and cover the whole page.

when i click on div the div should be popup and zoom. not changed the position of content with in it.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Make the contents of your popup size relative (10%) and add position:relative to it. Now you can do with it wjat you want without destroying the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS and change z-index of the div so it's on a new layer. Need sample to help you apply a solution.

Comment: is there any way to zoom that div like popup window .when i click on that div ,it should be zoom and like popup

Comment: @BhumirajDarbar hi, have u got solution? i too need that.

Comment: @Logeshwaran  apply all ineer div css in %(percentage) not in pixel so when outer div change the height and width of it than inner content of that div automatically set on that position.